# How can I override the 404 response in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, http-status-code-404

I'm building an api using ASP.NET MVC 3. When a controller action is not found I don't want the standard message and result returned. I want to respond with a json message containing additional data about the request. How can I override the default behavior which gives me the plain "Resource not found" page?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a great thread on here regarding this with very "MVCish" ways outside of generic error handling. There are multiple ways to do it - so rather than just repeat the thread, check it out:
[How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your web config and set up a route for the redirect.

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Errors/Error404/" />
</customErrors>
```